# Elasticsearch mapping geopoint unsuported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to set up an ELK to work with my PaloAlto firewall, but i'm stuck with the mappings. I have the following code :

```
"mappings":{
  "_default_":{
     "_all":{
        "enabled":true
     },
     "dynamic_templates":[
        {
           "message_field":{
              "match":"message",
              "match_mapping_type":"string",
              "mapping":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "index":"analyzed",
                 "omit_norms":true
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "string_fields":{
              "match":"*",
              "match_mapping_type":"string",
              "mapping":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "index":"analyzed",
                 "omit_norms":true,
                 "fields":{
                    "raw":{
                       "type":"string",
                       "index":"not_analyzed",
                       "ignore_above":256
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ],
     "properties":{
        "@version":{
           "type":"string",
           "index":"not_analyzed"
        },
        "geoip":{
           "type":"object",
           "dynamic":true,
           "path":"full",
           "properties":{
              "location":{
                 "type":"geo_point",
                 "lat_lon":true,
                 "geohash":true
              }
           }
        },
```

As I've seen in the official documentation, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/lat-lon.html you can put the param lat_lon to true to specify so it indexes it's values as numeric fields.

But instead i'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true] [lat_lon : true]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true] [lat_lon : true]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true] [lat_lon : true]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lat_lon and geohash properties. In the current elasticsearch version (5.2) these properties are not supported.

The following should do the trick:

```
    "geoip":{
       "dynamic":true,
       "properties":{
          "location":{
             "type":"geo_point"
          }
       }
    }
```

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

(If you are running 2.1 as your documentation link suggests, then feel free to ignore my answer)